# Ludwig when to use SET feature, SEQUENCE feature, examples data for both

Tags: ludwig

How to determine when to use `Set Features` vs `Sequence Features` on a column and difference between them with some examples.

I'm trying to use [Ludwig](https://uber.github.io/ludwig/) to perform classification. My dataset looks something like below:

- Letters here are just for representational purpose only
- For example feature 1 (alpha word) could stand for ^al lph pha ha$  (trigram here)

```
LABEL, Feature1, Feature2
X,     A B C,    D A E
X,     B C K,    K J L
Y,     A D C,    D A E
Y,     B D E,    J L R
```

```
        name: Feature1_trigrams
        type: set
        level: words
        encoder:
          representation: dense
          embedding_size: 10
          embeddings_on_cpu: false
          pretrained_embeddings: null
          embeddings_trainable: true
          dropout: false
          initializer: null
          regularize: true
          reduce_output: sqrt
          tied_weights: null
        cell_type: lstm
        bidirectional: true
        num_layers: 2
        reduce_output: null
        preprocessing:
          format: space
```

Should I be using Sequence instead?